# Azure Function Authenticating ASP.Net Core Web Api using Microsoft Account

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.0 Web App running in an App Service in Azure that has social login configured (Google & Microsoft) according to the following docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x

I also have an Azure Function app that gets triggered when a message is written to an Azure Queue. I would like this function app to post the message to a Web API (Controller Action) that is running on the web app above.

How would I go about authenticating from the function app to the web API method? Would I need to somehow call the Azure AD endpoint to get a token for a given username/password?

Ideally, I would want to limit who can call this API method to just a single user account that the function app would use. Alternatively, can I somehow use the new Managed Service Identity feature to authenticate the function app against my web API method in my web app above?

Sorry, am new to API authentication, so just trying to figure out the simplest approach.

Comment: If I undesrtand correctly, you want to access one Azure Web app from an Azure Function and use MSA to authentication. Well, for this scenario, I think you can [enable authentication with login with Microsoft Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication). It will register a AAD v2 endpoint App and you can use it to get token for your Function.

Comment: As I indicated in my question, I already have Microsoft Account sign-in enabled in my app using this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x. How would the Azure Function go about getting a token from AAD v2 endpoint using MSI?